# Matplotlib: set linewidth before plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a method in matplotlib to set the attributes of a plot BEFORE actually plotting it?
To the context: I have a config file in which I configure aspects of a plot. However, some keys may not be needed to be set (as e.g. the linewidth). I would like to have a function which says something like this :

```
if 'linethicknes' in config:
       ax.set_linewidth = linethickness
```

I know that there is the possibility to give the linewidth property in the `ax.plot(x, y ,linewidth = 1)`. But here the attribute is set in the plotting function, and I need to set it before the plotting.
Is it possibile to set the linewidth (and other attributes) before this plotting function?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the runtime configuration [rcparams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) at the start and this will set the configuration. As long as you don't overwrite it, this will be set as the configuration. A simple example is given below...

```
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 6.0

x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[5,4,3,2,1]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]